# ASP.NET Friendly URLs 404 errors

Tags: asp.net, friendly-url

When I start a web app by loading a page deep in the site, I consistently get a 404 error when using ASP.NET Friendly URLs.

I can reproduce this by:

1. Start web app by loading page in website root
2. Navigate to page such as /Manage/ViewEmployee/1
3. iisreset
4. Reload page /Manage/ViewEmployee/1

Step 4 will always result in a 404 error. I can reproduce this consistently in my test environment:

- Windows 2008 R2
- IIS 7.5
- ASP.NET 4.5
- Microsoft ASP.NET Friendly URLs 1.0.0

I cannot reproduce this issue, however, with IIS Express on Windows 7.

Are there any web.config settings that I can add to address this with IIS 7.5?

Answer (score 0):

Were you able to load the page in the first place by entering the URL in the browser? I suspect the issue to be a problem with the URL and not with the IISRESET. Since you are using the latest version of IIS, there should be no problems with the settings too for handling friendly url's.

Comment: If I first load a page in the web site root, then load /Manage/ViewEmployee/1 it works just fine.  If I then do an iisreset, and reload /Manage/ViewEmployee/1 (without loading any other pages first), I get a 404 error.  Also, if I look in the IIS logs, I can see several 200s and several 404s for that exact same url

Comment: can you please post the entire url? you can view the urls on the 'net' tab of firebug tool to see if your url is properly formed.